# Python - How to get a function to actually return `None`?

Tags: python

Output for:

```
def test(c):
    if c == 4:
       return None
    return 'test'
```

returns `'test'` given anything I put in such as `test(500)` but when I try `test(4)` the function simply skips and pretends I never ran it, but I want it to show `None`. So,

```
>> test(500)
'test'
>> test(4)
>>
```

is what happens. My goal is for a `None` to return without having to use print in the function:

```
>> test(4)
None
```

Help!

Comment: But it does return `None`. It just happens to not show that to you, but the return value is indeed `None`.

Comment: @univerio How can I get it to show in the output?

Comment: You can confirm it's returning None by doing `print test(4)` then you'll see the `None` return value that is there as others have indicated

Comment: The title of my canonical doesn't mention this specific case, but the Q&A covers it. (The title is already quite long, so I couldn't figure out a way to work it in.) The general question is about *how the REPL handles the result of expressions*; it doesn't print `None` results, but it does print others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`None` is the result returned by things that "don't return anything", like `list.sort` or the Python 3 `print` function. If an expression you type at the interactive prompt evaluates to `None`, Python won't automatically print it, since it thinks you probably called a "doesn't return anything" function, and it would be confusing to have sessions like

```
>>> l = [3, 2, 1]
>>> l.sort()
None
>>> print(l)
[1, 2, 3]
None
```

If you want to print it anyway, you need to explicitly `print` it.

Answer (score 3):

It is returning None.  Nothing is printed, because the output shows the result, which is None, which is nothing, so it is not shown.

Answer (score 2):

It is returning `None`. If you want to see that this is true without putting `print` in the method definition, you can do this:

```
print test(4)
> None
```